# Bootstrap toggle buttons dont work following the recommended documentation

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I use Bootstrap 4 and following the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) i implemented a toggle button group like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="checkbox">Test
  </label>
</div>
```

The toggle is supposed to change the buttons active state so i added the following css to change the buttons color and background-color when toggled:

```
.btn.btn-secondary {
  color: BLACK;
  background-color: WHITE;
}

.btn.btn-secondary.active {
  color: WHITE;
  background-color: BLACK;
}
```

The problem is that the button doesnt toggle. It doesnt switch to the active state when clicked.

Then i found this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/toggle-button?file=app%2Fbuttons-checkbox.html). It doesnt use `data-toggle="buttons"`,but it adds ng-bootstraps `ngbButtonLabel` and `ngbButton` to the `label` and `input`.

By following that example of the stackblitz and applying it to my code the toggle button functionality works correctly:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary" ngbButtonLabel>
    <input type="checkbox" ngbButton>Test
  </label>
</div>
```

I would like to know, why doesnt the way i tried to implement it the first time following bootstraps documentaiton work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just the selector problem. apply css by selecting particular element with its parent class. not need to apply any css using !important.

see the below snippet

```css
.btn-group label.btn.btn-secondary {
  color: BLACK;
  background-color: WHITE;
}

.btn-group label.btn.btn-secondary.active {
  color: WHITE;
  background-color: BLACK;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Demo Page</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
   <input type="checkbox">Test
  </label>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   May it will help.

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
    .btn.btn-secondary {
      color: BLACK;
      background-color: WHITE;
    }

   .btn.btn-secondary.active {
     color: WHITE;
     background-color: BLACK;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">



        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
        <input type="checkbox">Test
      </label>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this article about [CSS Specificity](https://dev.to/emmawedekind/css-specificity-1kca). 
If you are using bootstrap events (in this case you are using a button which toggles a css class) remember to import the optional JavaScript file.

```css
body {
  padding: 2rem;
}
.btn.btn-secondary,
.btn.btn-secondary:hover {
  color: BLACK;
  background-color: WHITE;
}

.btn.btn-secondary.active {
  color: WHITE;
  background-color: BLACK;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off"> Checked
  </label>
</div>
```